# create a meeting invite in outlook 2011 using apple script

Tags: scripting, outlook, applescript, osx-mavericks

I am trying to create a meeting invite in outlook 2011 using apple script. I have open the dictionary for outlook meeting class

[image]

and I tried to create meeting event using

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"

    set currentTime to (the current date)

    set newEvent to make new calendar event with properties {location:"Dial In : +4319284090,  Conference code: 5270687926", start time:(currentTime + (60 * 60)), end time:(currentTime + (60 * 60) + (60 * 60) / 2), content:fileContents}

    set newMeeting to make new meeting message with properties {meeting:newEvent}
    open newMeeting

end tell
```

but i am getting the error

```
error "Microsoft Outlook got an error: AppleEvent handler failed." number -10000
```

does any one can help me, I will appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 0):

According to the dictionary, a `meeting message` is `A meeting message recieved by the user.` This is not the actual message that goes out as invitations. In other words, a `meeting message` is the message that shows up in your inbox when someone else invites you to a meeting.

The `calendar event` has an `attendee` property. I wasn't able to get it to work in the 10 minutes I spent playing with it, but my assumption is an invitation will go out to `attendees` when the calendar event is created.

Note that `attendee` is a read-only list. When you create the event, you have to specify a list of `required attendees` and `optional attendees`.